# Crash in Google maps cocoapod in iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

My project is using GoogleMap (8.3.0) version. It is working all good.
But suddenly it is crashing with the error :

`*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: key cannot be nil -[GMSStyleTableService checkStyleTableMemoryCacheForKey:callbackQueue:handler:]`

Here is what i tried to make sure mapview is not nil :

```objectivec
if(self.mapView==nil) return;

self.mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:pathString];

GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithPath:path];

GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
polyline.strokeWidth = 3;
polyline.strokeColor = color.blue;
polyline.map = self.mapView;

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [self.mapView cameraForBounds:bounds insets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(32, 32, 32, 32)];
self.mapView.camera = camera;

GMSMarker *myMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
myMarker.position = self.myCoords;
myMarker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.png"];
myMarker.map = self.mapView;
```